# How to find plain text from RSA cipher text

Tags: rsa, public-key, encryption-asymmetric, encryption

I have a RSA cipher text `c`, the public key `(e,n)`. (where `c = m^e mod n`)

Now I also have known the plain text `m` should be either `"1234XXX"` or `"12345XXX"`, where `"XXX"` is a 3 digit number.

Can I find which one is right without testing all 3 digits number? (I just want to know if the first part is `"1234"` or `"12345"`, and I don't care what the `XXX` is.)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking; are you trying to brute-force guess the secret key given the public key, plaintext, and ciphertext? Given that that's the usual operating mode for RSA, it should be difficult to derive the secret key from just these inputs. Can you re-phrase your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that (it's a sort of know-plain-text attack). You can't derive any information on the key nor on the plain text, given an encrypted RSA message.

(Similar plain text messages don't produce similar encrypted messages)

So in your case, where you have the public key, you are still forced to encrypt all possible plain input messages (brute force), to discover the related encrypted messages.

Comment: Well, at least I can test 1000 times on one possible messages(worst case), and compare the results `m'^e mod n` with c. If none of them are right. Then it must be the second one. But is there no shortcut?

Comment: @Chris: no shortcut. I would be scared of a shortcut beacuse it would imply an RSA weakness. (It wouldn't be possible because RSA is proved to be secure unless you can find an easy way to factorize prime numbers )

Comment: @Chris + 1 - You are right. You can brute force generate all strings and encrypt to see which one matches the known cypher text. But there is no short cut, because to generate the target cypher text, you have to know _exactly_ what the clear text was. You can't generate part of the clear text and hope to sort of "partially match" the cypher text.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you use RSA *properly*, then you cannot even guess your 'XXX' by trying the 1000 possibilities. The core operation in RSA is a modular exponentiation, but there is a first step called *padding* which transforms the data to encrypt into a big integer (modulo *n*).

The [PKCS#1 RSA standard](https://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-rsa-cryptography-standard.htm) specifies two types of padding; both include a bunch of random bytes. A consequence is the following: if you encrypt twice the same message with the same key, you will get two *distinct* encrypted messages. The point is, precisely, to avoid the situation which you allude to: being able to "guess" the encrypted message and verify whether the guess is right or not, with only the public key (which is public, hence assumed to be known by every attacker).

Therefore, to answer your question: *if* you can find your 'XXX', either by trying only 1000 RSA encryption, or through any kind of clever shortcut, *then* your RSA is very wrong.